# Inductive effect of acetyl group

Tags: inductive-effect

**Question:**
[image]

Since the acetyl group provides $-M$, methyl $+I$ and chlorine $-I$, it is obvious that the correct order is as given in option $(a)$

However while solving such questions I would compare the inductive effect as well as resonance effect. Thats where I wondered what could be the inductive effect acetyl group has to offer

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlying principles and solve the question. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. ( As homework is considered literal homework, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.) Please provide your full reasoning or thoughts on this, otherwise, the question may get closed.‎ See [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. This is a straightforward question. I couldn't decide whether it shows +I or -I.

Comment: I didn't get you. Which carbon is electron deficient and why? The other is amino group

Comment: So, it would be better if you could post an image of the question and what your thoughts were. is it  $\ce{-COCH3}$? and $\ce{-NH2}$. the groups attached. If so then the carbon attached is electron deficient and so has a -I effect

Comment: You should draw the resonance structures. In the para- position, the inductive effect is dwarfed by the resonance contribution.

Comment: Even if the inductive effect is small, what could it be?